# How many sausages are there in Stephen's Sausage Roll?

Tags: stephens-sausage-roll

How many sausages are there in [Stephen's Sausage Roll](http://www.stephenssausageroll.com/)? I have read that some people finished the game with 215 sausages, others with 220 sausages, but what is the definitive total?

[image: A fork for sausages]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 220 sausages* in the game.  And if you beat the game, you will have grilled 220 sausages.  When you finish the game, the save slot will still say 215, but I would consider that a quirk.

*it can be argued there are 221

**SPOILERS** Full breakdown

> **WORLD 1** (16 levels, 32 sausages)
>
>  2 Southjaunt
>
>  2 Fiery Jut
>
>  1 Maiden's Walk
>
>  1 Happy Pool
>
>  2 Merchant's Elegy
>
>  2 Seafinger
>
>  3 The Clover
>
>  2 Inlet Shore
>
>  3 The Anchorage
>
>  3 Lachrymose Head
>
>  2 Infant's Break
>
>  2 Comely Hearth
>
>  2 Little Fire
>
>  2 Eastreach
>
>  1 Bay's Neck
>
>  2 Burning Wharf
>
>  
>  **WORLD 2** (10 levels, 23 sausages)
>
>  1 Sad Farm
>
>  2 Cove
>
>  2 Rough Field
>
>  2 Barrow Set
>
>  2 The Paddock
>
>  2 Beautiful Horizon
>
>  1 Fallow Earth
>
>  1 Emerson Jetty
>
>  8 The Great Tower
>
>  2 Twisty Farm
>
>  
>  **WORLD 3** (13 levels, 43 sausages)
>
>  3 Cold Trail
>
>  2 Cold Escarpment
>
>  3 Cold Finger
>
>  2 Cold Pit
>
>  2 Cold Plateau
>
>  3 Cold Terrace
>
>  5 Cold Sausage
>
>  2 Cold Head
>
>  3 Cold Ladder
>
>  2 Cold Horizon
>
>  3 Cold Cliff
>
>  3 Cold Jag
>
>  7 Cold Gate
>
>  3 Cold Frustration
>
>  
>  **WORLD 4** (6 levels, 12 sausages)
>
>  2 Wretch's Retreat
>
>  3 Toad's Folly
>
>  2 Sludge Coast
>
>  1 Gator Paddock
>
>  1 Foul Fen
>
>  3 Crunchy Leaves
>
>  
>  **WORLD 5** (11 levels, 29 sausages)
>
>  1 Land's End
>
>  3 Slope View
>
>  2 Pressure Points
>
>  2 Crater
>
>  3 Skeleton
>
>  3 The Gorge
>
>  3 Open Baths
>
>  2 Rough View
>
>  2 Tarry Ridge
>
>  2 Baby Rock
>
>  3 Drumlin
>
>  3 Widow's Finger
>
>  
>  **Final Sequence** (28 levels, 76 sausages)
>
>  2 Dead End
>
>  2 Sea Dragon
>
>  4 Folklore
>
>  4 The Decay
>
>  2 The Splitting Bough
>
>  2 Captive Hydra
>
>  1 Rattlesnakes
>
>  2 Sty
>
>  3 Split Face
>
>  2 Four-faced Liar
>
>  3 Suspension Bridge
>
>  3 Curious Dragons
>
>  2 Ancient Dam
>
>  1 Apex
>
>  2 The Stone Tree
>
>  3 The Backbone
>
>  2 Baby Swan
>
>  3 Shy Dragon
>
>  3 Lover's Sadness
>
>  2 Dragonclaw
>
>  2 Obscene Gesture
>
>  4 The Nursery
>
>  3 Canal
>
>  3 Mommy Swan
>
>  2 Loft of the Spirit
>
>  1 Wobblecliff
>
>  4 Plateau Ferry
>
>  9 God Pillar
>
>  
>  **Outer World** (5 sausages - after grilling these 5, the game ends.  it appears impossible to have a save state after doing so)
>
>  1 bridging worlds 1 and 2
>
>  1 bridging worlds 2 and 3
>
>  1 bridging worlds 3 and 4
>
>  1 bridging worlds 4 and 5
>
>  1 revealed after God Pillar
>
>  
>  **After Game Completion** (arguably 1 sausage) 
>
>  1 - the main character turns into a block, the same kind that turns into a sausage throughout the game.  the in-game text also heavily implies that people turn into sausages

Comment: Why can it be argued that there are 221?

Comment: I put more details in a spoiler :)

Comment: That's more helpful, though, you really only needed to put the very last few lines in a spoiler. I wasn't quite sure what would be considered a spoiler until I got to the end and was like "oh" so I'm sure others will do the same.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree.  rot13: Gur ahzore bs fnhfntrf tevyyrq va Qrnq Raq vf n qrsvavgr fcbvyre, nf jryy nf gur snpg gung V pbafvqrerq vg abg gb or va Jbeyq 5.  Znqr gur zbfg frafr gb zr gb whfg pbafvqre gur jubyr guvat n fcbvyre ng gung cbvag.  Cyhf, fbzr cynlref zvtug abg rira jnag gb xabj ubj znal jbeyqf, yriryf cre jbeyq, rgp.